# jQuery, Select nested element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I select

```
$("a.tp[programm='" + programm + "']");
```

then I want to select its nested element *span.thump* and set the text of it. How do i realize that?

```
<h4><a programm="74" class="tp" href="#"><img src="/images/tuo.png"></a><a href="">
<img width="180" height="40" src="/images/kauf_default.png"><br>test 
<span class="thump">1</span><img src="/images/ilike.png"></a></h4>
```

Comment: Could you post the html too, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
<a class="tp" programm="foo">blah <span class="thump">setTextOfThis</span> blah</a>
```

? If so, try

```
$("a.tp[programm='" + programm + "'] span.thump").text(newText);
```

---

Edit: Regarding the update, try

```
$("a.tp[programm='" + programm + "'] + a span.thump").text(newText);
```

(You may want `... ~ a span.thump` if the `<a>` containing that `<span>` is not immediately next to that `<a programm>`.

Comment: postet my html code above, this solution does not work I tried already

Comment: what is the `+` operator doing here? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: the + is just concatanating the strings to build the selector.  programm is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `<span>` you are looking for is not a child of that `<a>` tag you are selecting, so you will need to traverse to the [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com) node and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) the correct child.

```
$("a.tp[programm='" + programm + "']").parent().find('.thump');
```

Comment: why not just use `siblings()` ?